# Espanso replacement not working outside of terminal

Tags: bash, jq

I've put together a replacement script of [Espanso](https://espanso.org/), so a call to an API is done and it returns a url contained on the response to the API.
This is the .yml chunk I've created:

```
  - regex: ":spongebob\\((?P<meme>.*)\\)"
    replace: "{{meme_result}}"
    vars:
      - name: meme_result
        type: shell
        params:
          cmd: "curl -s --request POST 'https://api.imgflip.com/caption_image?template_id=182442076&text0={{meme}}&username=user&password=paswword' | jq -r '.data.url'"
```

The `curl` command returns something like:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"url":"https:\/\/i.imgflip.com\/6yblu0.jpg","page_url":"https:\/\/imgflip.com\/i\/6yblu0"}}
```

and running it with jq does return a valid url:

```
>> curl -s --request POST 'https://api.imgflip.com/caption_image?template_id=182442076&text0=test&username=user&password=password' | jq -r '.data.url'
<<https://i.imgflip.com/6ybmkf.jpg
```

Not sure where the problem is (jq? bash? espanso?), but if I run the espanso command on a terminal, then the url is returned correctly:
`https://i.imgflip.com/6ybmkf.jpg`

However, if I run it anywhere else (this form, for example), typing `:spongebob(sd)`
then I get the url without the `:` on it:
`https//i.imgflip.com/6ybxtu.jpg`
Obviously destroying the usage of it.

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Comment: Definitely not jq. Neither bash. My money is on Espanso.

Comment: The colon seems pretty special for espanso. Do you need to escape it in some way?

Comment: I don't know I can escape it from the output of the API, I tried some `sed s#https//#https://#g` with no  luck

Comment: I think you'll probably want to do something like `s/:/\:/g` (or whatever escape character is required)? Full disclosure: I'm guessing here